# how do i install inception model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used this link for downloading inception model but it should be this error:

```sh
$ pip install http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz
Collecting 


100% |################################| 88.9MB 491kB/s
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Waleed\Anaconda3\envs\py35_tf_cpu\lib\tokenize.py", line 454, in open

    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'C:\\Users\\Waleed\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-cokfajr0-build\\setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Waleed\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-cokfajr0-build\
```

How do I install the inception model?

Answer (score 1):

Don't install the inception network using pip. As the error states, there is no `setup.py` file because it is not a Python egg, it's just a bunch of files:

```
$ tar xzf inception-2015-12-05.tgz
$ ls 
LICENSE
classify_image_graph_def.pb
cropped_panda.jpg
imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt
imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt
inception-2015-12-05.tgz
```

A better way to build and use the inception model is to get it (or one of the many other pre-trained TensorFlow models) from the [tensorflow/models github repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/inception). There are instructions specifically for building the [inception model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/inception). You'll need [Bazel](http://www.bazel.io/).